# UIGestureRecognizer or touchesBegan not responding

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have a normal app. Yes this will not work anywhere in it. If I place this in a ViewController, it will not work, if I place this in a UIView subclass, likewise, it refuses to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Please Work");
}
```

Comment: `touchesBegan:withEvent:` goes on a `UIView` subclass.

Maybe there is a problem on how you are adding that view to screen. Perhaps you can show some code of how you are attempting this?

Comment: @Ismael: not true. `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is a method of `UIResponder`. Since both `UIView` and `UIViewController` inherit from `UIResponder`, the method both can be implemented in either place.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the view has userInteractionEnabled=YES. If a parent view has userInteractionEnabled=NO, the touches will be lost too. If that doesn't help, post code.